# How do I limit the number of rows per id on an oracle database?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to store the last 20 products a user has looked at. If the user browses to product number 21 the oldest of the records should be deleted from the ORACLE database.

The table contains the recently viewed products of all the users in the system.

So basically I need to check if user X has over Y records in a table and if so delete the oldest records so that user X only ever has Y records in the recently viewed products table.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is an attempt I have made which does not work correctly.

```
DELETE FROM VIEWED_PRODUCT
WHERE id NOT IN (
  SELECT id
  FROM (
    SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT id
      FROM VIEWED_PRODUCT
      WHERE MY_ID = 1626
      ORDER BY CREATED_AT DESC )
        WHERE ROWNUM <= 20 
  ) z
);
```

Thanks.

Comment: This seems like a terrible idea to do dynamically in the database.  Is there any reason you can't store this in the application and update the DB once the user browses `X` pages or closes/saves/performs some other trigger action?

Comment: +1 not for your question but for your MEGA MAN avatar.

Comment: @JNK: maybe it's a web application? i.e. can't guarantee user will perform the trigger action.

Comment: @Tony - then you can update once they d/c or within 5 mins of last action or something else.  Inserting/deleting a row every time every user looks at every page seems like a terrible design

Comment: @JNK: true.  In fact, a job to do it periodically for all users might work well.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I will be considering other options. Just wanted to see what this solution would look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use analytic functions like this:

```
delete viewed_product where id in
( select id from
  ( select id, row_number() over (order by created_at desc) rn
    from viewed_product
    where my_id = :bindvar
  )
  where rn > 20
)
```